# Symfony 2 - Use /gecko/{name}/show instead of /gecko/{id}/show

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to symfony so please excuse any simple mistakes.

I have generated a CRUD for my geckos through the console. Everything works, all very good. However, what i would like to do is use the name in the URL rather than the ID and make the queries work as intended. For example:

Current i have `http://breedr.dev/app_dev.php/gecko/1/show` but i would like it to be `http://breedr.dev/app_dev.php/gecko/Zilly/show` - i hope this makes sense.

This is my `showAction` in my `Gecko` controller:

```
public function showAction($name)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->find($name);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Gecko entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($name);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

But my problem is i get "Unable to find Gecko entity.". After looking at the log i can see this is happening:

```
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.aquisition_date AS aquisition_date3, t0.morph AS morph4, t0.sex AS sex5, t0.genetics AS genetics6, t0.bio AS bio7, t0.bred AS bred8, t0.hatchling AS hatchling9, t0.clutch AS clutch10, t0.image_name AS image_name11, t0.updatedAt AS updatedAt12 FROM Gecko t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
```

Obviously here you can see the `WHERE` is using the `id` field when it should be name. What is it i need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->find($name);
```

change to

```
 $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->findOneByName($name);
```

Regarding your question about doc:

I can't quickly find doc referrer, but I think it is just mater of understanding of Doctrine "magic" methods.

If you will look to the source code 
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php so you will see that "find" method uses "id" as expected param, but if you need get another criteria, then you should use doctrine "magic" as findBy%Field% (for multiply records) or findOneBy%Field% (for single record)

Update2:
But if you will need to search by multiply values then you should use 
findBy(array('age' => 20, 'surname' => 'Miller')) or findOneBy(array('age' => 20, 'surname' => 'Miller')) according

Comment: `Key "id" for array with keys "0" does not exist in src/Breedr/GeckoBundle/Resources/views/Gecko/show.html.twig at line 10`

line 10 being `{{ entity.id }}`

Comment: Spot on! Thank you :) Where about's in the docs is this explained?

Comment: I added little explanation

Comment: That's great, thank you. I'll be allowing users to sing up to this, so is it possible concatenate it further by saying something like `findOneByNameAndUsername` ?

Comment: Perfect, thanks for explaining that. You've been a great help :)